# Setting Business Intelligence Development Studio Temp File Location

Tags: sql-server, bids, ssis

Is there a way to specify where temp files are created when building SSIS packages using SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio? Currently it saves them at C:\Documents and Settings\\Local Settings\Temp. Our C: has limited space, so we are getting warnings about low disk and have concern of running out. I've found some file settings under Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions, but they are for project and template locations, not temp files.

Thanks for any practical help.

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the Environment variable TMP value to determine where SSIS should save the temporary files.

If you would like to change the temporary location path at the user level, change the value indicated by the arrow **1**.

To change the temporary path for the machine, change the value indicated by the arrow **2**.

On Windows 7 machine, the path is Start **-->** Control Panel **-->** System and Security *(if you see the icons by category else skip to next)* **-->** System **-->** Advanced system settings **-->** Advanced tab **-->** Environment Variables...

Hope that helps.

[image: TMP variable]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the TMP environment variable (from [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/d493f083-89fa-40fd-a217-68546e280d8d))